# Python Regex - Is it possible to use the same group (named or unnamed) in multiple spots?

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings, *some* of which I need to replace a part of. However, the parts before and after the parts that need to be replaced are not always the same. Also, the part of the string that needs to be replaced is not something I can match with a regex without it matching other parts that I don't want to replace. For example:

```
"prefixA_REPLACEME_postfixA",
"prefixB_SOMETHING_postfixB",
"prefixA_LLAMAS_postfixC",
"prefixB_DONTREPLACE_postfixA",
```

Turned into:

```
"prefixA_NEWSTR_postfixA",
"prefixB_NEWSTR_postfixB",
"prefixA_NEWSTR_postfixC",
"prefixB_DONTREPLACE_postfixA",
```

I would love to do this with a single regex, like this:

```
re.sub('(prefixA_).*(_postfixA)|(prefixB_).*(_postfixB)|(prefixA_).*(_postfixC)', '\\1NEWSTR\\2', stringToFix)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because group 1 and group 2 are `(prefixA_)` and `(postfixA)`, whether or not that is the part of the regex that ends up being used. I also can't use this

```
re.sub('(?P<one>prefixA_).*(?P<two>_postfixA)|(?P<one>prefixB_).*(?P<two>_postfixB)|(?P<one>prefixA_).*(?P<two>_postfixC)', '\\1NEWSTR\\2', stringToFix)
```

because it gives me the error

```
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'one' as group 3; was group 1
```

Something else that won't work is this

```
re.sub('(prefixA_|prefixB).*(_postfixA|_postfixB|_postfixC)', '\\1NEWSTR\\2', stringToFix)
```

because this would capture the fourth string, which I don't want to be matched.

So is there a way to make it so that any uncaptured groups are not counted (which would make my first regex work correctly)? Or any other way to do this with a single regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a named capturing group more than once within the same regex (unlike other regex flavors like .NET). But since you're not doing anything with the pre- and postfixes, you can simply use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> s = """prefixA_REPLACEME_postfixA
... prefixB_SOMETHING_postfixB
... prefixA_LLAMAS_postfixC
... prefixB_DONTREPLACE_postfixA"""
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub("(?<=prefixA).*(?=postfixA)|(?<=prefixB).*(?=postfixB)|(?<=prefixA).*(?=postfixC)", "_NEWSTR_", s)
prefixA_NEWSTR_postfixA
prefixB_NEWSTR_postfixB
prefixA_NEWSTR_postfixC
prefixB_DONTREPLACE_postfixA
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like what you want to do is use

```
if re.search("shouldReplaceRegex",matchstring): matchstring = re.sub("_.*?_","_yourReplacement_",matchstring)
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, but I the parts that I need to replace are varied enough that anything that would be able to match all of them would also match many things that I don't want to replace.